# Update php page, show results of background program and move to next page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, page-refresh

I have a webpage to get input data file as well as settings. Background program takes the file and process it (takes 2-3 mins to complete). After submission, I like to move to a new page and it has to be refreshed automatically for every 10 seconds to show updates from the program. After analysis gets over, i like to move to results page. How to do this in php?
 Something like [NCBI BLAST](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome)

Comment: How about using AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX and refresh your webpage containt as much as you want and you can use the header function in PHP to takes you to the page you want to go to.
Expl : header(Location: http://www.mylink.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to Update few parts of Your Page Or you can simply use

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="10; URL=''">
```

To completely refresh current page ,here 10 is the number of seconds you want your page to be refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do:

Using Meta Tag:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="; URL=">
```

Using Ajax

```
$.get() || $.post() || $.ajax() || $.load()
```

Using PHP Header redirection:

```
header("Location:...");
```

Using javascript refresh or reload after a time slot:

```
window.setTimeOut(window.reload,1000)
```